# Comparing a set of values to a changing expected set of values to give score out of $10$

Tags: algorithms

I'm kind of a math noob, and I'm developing a web app that's in dire need of a scoring algorithm.

The basis of it is that were scoring influencers on their influence. I want our score to go something like this if $x$% of followers like and y% of likes comment then the score is a $10$. How could I implement a multiplier that'd allow me to change the $x$ and $y$ while comparing it to actual values.

Sorry for the lengthy question!

Best,
Ethan

Comment: I don't understand your filter.  I gather users are scored in two dimensions.  If you have a deterministic rule that passes from a score $(x,y)$ to some integer in $[0,10]$ (or whatever), just implement that rule, no?  Or is this being done without some pre-determined rule?  But if so, you need to provide clearer infomration.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for you're reply. The score from 0 to 10 and the y and x are different. The y is the % of followers liking and the x is the % of likes commenting. I want to compare this to a diminishing returns graph(because the more followers the smaller like and comment %). That is the rule if that makes any sense.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't clarify things.  I understood (and said in my comment) that $x,y$ represented different scoring dimensions.  If you want to include other dimensions (like the size(s) of the respective voting pool(s)) of course you can, but I don't think we can guess what you have in mind.